# What's that app or library that allows one to add functionality to cocoa apps?

Tags: cocoa

I recall reading about an application or library that allows to add some functionality to Cocoa apps.
I found it when searching for an application for using mouse gestures in Finder and applications other than browsers, but I didn't pay too much attention to it because I didn't know Objective-C or Cocoa at the time.
Do you have any idea of which one could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php)?